# Passing user-defined feature selection (by location) into geoprocessing widget in web app

Tags: web-mapping, python-script-tool, web-service, geoprocessing-service, feature-service

I am creating a web based map with a custom script tool that is published as a geoprocessing service. I am using app builder to set up a geoprocessing widget, but am unsure of how to include a user selection.

I would like the user to be able to select features from a feature service layer in the web map (by drawing a polygon around the ones they want to select), and pass only the selected features into the geoprocessing widget that will run the script tool.

My initial thought is to have the user create a layer using a feature set and then write a select by location into the script to select features from another layer. However, I am unsure of what data type to use for the layer I want to make the selection on.

Is there an easier way to do this by using the select widget? Can you select features using the select widget and then pass only these selected features into the geoprocessing widget?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating the geoprocessing widget using an input parameter of type 'FeatureSet'? The geoprocessing widget will then use the selected features in the processing. See a [quick tour](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-feature-set-and-record-set.htm) here.